# Form edit not working even if I have added formGroup name

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups

Here am using dynamic formGroup for add/edit/list data. Am facing one issue while editing the data ie the patchvalue() is not properly working in the case of editing data.

Angular markup

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" 
   aria-labelledby="Modal" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="Modal">Create</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup] = "Form" (ngSubmit) = "FormSubmit()">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-4 col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center mb-15">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control modal-input" 
   formControlName="Name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-4 col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center mb-15">
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="Employee">
          <option>Select</option>
          <option value="{{employee.id}}" *ngFor = "let employee of employees"> {{ 
    employee.name }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-20">
      <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center ">
        <table class="table" formArrayName="EmployeeDetails">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Person</th>
              <th scope="col">Duties</th>
              <th scope="col">Protocols</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr  *ngFor="let duty of employeeDuties().controls;let i=index" 
         [formGroupName]="i">
              <td>
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="Person" >
                  <option>Select</option>
                  <option value="{{ user.id }}" *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.name }}</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="Duty">   
                  <option>Select</option>
                  <option>Duty1</option>
                  <option>Duty2</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
                  <mat-select  #pSelect multiple formControlName="ProtocolsNames" >
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let protocol of protocols" [value]="protocol.id">
                      {{protocol.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </td>
              <td><button type="button" (click)="delete(i)"> alt="Delete" ></button>
              </td>
              <td><button type="button" (click)="add()" > alt="Add" ></button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
   </form>
```

TypeScript

```
constructor() {


  this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [''], 
  Name: [''],
  Employee: [''],
  ProtocolsNames: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
 }

 editData (Id:string) {
    this.service.getData(Id)  //i could console the id here
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((item:any) => 
        this.Form.setValue({
          id: item.id,
          Name: item.Name, 
          Employee: item.Employee,
          ProtocolsNames: item.ProtocolsNames 
        })
    );
   }

  employeeDuties() : FormArray {
    return this.Form.get("employeeDuties") as FormArray
  }

  newDuty(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
     Person: '',
     Duty: '',
     ProtocolNames: ''
    })
   }

  add() {
   this.employeeDuties().push(this.newDuty());
  }
```

Am getting always this error in console "Cannot find form control with name: id". I have tried adding formgroupname for the nested html elements but still not working.

Comment: Tried to create a Stackblitz demo with the above code but seems like too many errors. Please review your code and try to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com). Thanks.

Comment: I can't see formControlName="id" in your html, if you didn't show that so remove it from form and just add it when you want get/post data

Comment: @kian first time id wont be there, when i click on edit data button from the data list the editdata method will be called with the id and trying to set  the id value to form group here ,  this.Form.setValue({
          id: item.id, 
This method is working for other forms that am sure, but no idea why this error happens here!

Comment: @YongShun i will try..Thanks for helping!